# "mimetype: application" display on a picture instead of "mimetype: image" after a ImageIO.write

Tags: java, image, file-io, mime-types

When I simply create a new image from another like this:

```
  public static void scaleByTwoRight(String src, String dest)
    throws IOException {
           BufferedImage bsrc = ImageIO.read(new File(src));
           int width          = bsrc.getWidth()/2;
           int height         = bsrc.getHeight();
           BufferedImage bdest = bsrc.getSubimage(width, 0, width, height);
           ImageIO.write(bdest,"PNG",new File(dest));
  }
```

Source file (src) = C:...\Manga\Shonan Juna_ Gumi Tome 11\Shonan Junaï Gumi Tome 11 - 091B.png
Destination file (dest) = C:...\Manga\Shonan Junaï Gumi Tome 11 - 091B_A.png

Example of generated file: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1vKCZzB5hxqYzNsUWF5RHA2Wm8/edit?usp=sharing

Problem: The new image has mimetype: application instead of mimetype: image

How I arrive to this conclusion: I'm using a function to test if the file is an image or not:

```
public static boolean isImage(String src)
    throws IOException {
          File f = new File(src);
          String mimetype= new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(f);
          String type = mimetype.split("/")[0];
          if(type.equals("image")){
              return true;
          }else{ 
              System.out.println("mimetype: "+type);
              return false;
          }
  }
```

It has not a huge impact if the Mime-type is not correct but I prefer to have that working properly..

Thanks for your help!

Note:
I'm running under Windows 7 / 32b 
JVM 1.7 / Eclipse Helios

Comment: `String dest`  What is the value of `dest`?  Answer in the form of an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) please.

Comment: Function : scaleByTwoRight(String src, String dest)

Source file (src) = C:\...\Manga\Shonan Juna_ Gumi Tome 11\Shonan Junaï Gumi Tome 11 - 091B.png
Destination file (dest) = C:\...\Manga\Shonan Junaï Gumi Tome 11 - 091B_A.png

Comment: Please find an example of the destination (image) created after running scaleByTwoRight function: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1vKCZzB5hxqYzNsUWF5RHA2Wm8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: 1) Don't put code in comments or links, add them directly as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15967480/edit) 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine in my machine.
I have windows XP,32 bit,
Tried with jpeg image and it is returning the mimetype as image/jpeg only.
Hope you are not trying to execute both the functions simultaneously.
Also the destination file name should contain proper extension like .jpeg or. png etc...

Comment: Hi Mitpatoliya, When I check from the explorer, it looks correct > File > Item type > PNG Image. But if I run the function isImage(..) it returns Application type. I think that I have to manually create the mime-type while creating the file or something similar.. http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0487.html

Comment: what is the destination path you are passing?

Comment: *"Tried with jpeg image.."*  Why JPEG when the code snippets are obviously set to create a PNG?

Comment: there are various ways to get the mimetypes from file.Most of them use the file name extension to findout the relative mimetype from the map.So, if you do not have file with proper extension then you will not get the proper mimetype mostly that was my point.